# How to notify the main function that a call to an asynchronous function fails?

Tags: javascript

Having a validation function, in this function there are three calls to asynchronous functions that execute independent conditions of the validation process, these asynchronous functions return the following object:

```
{status: true|false, message: void|string}
```

`status` is set to `true` if the validation in turn is successfully otherwise it is set to `false` and a `message` is added.

The requirement is: The `validator` function must return early, that is, if any asynchronous validation fails, it must stop there and return the reason for the failure in the object.

I attach an emulation of the implementation using callbacks because I can not use `async/await`:

```js
function validator() {
    validation1(response => {
        if (response.status === false) {
            console.log('Here in validation1 validator needs to return response');
        }
    });

    validation2(response => {
        if (response.status === false) {
            console.log('Here in validation2 validator needs to return response');
        }
    });

    validation3(response => {
        if (response.status === false) {
            console.log('Here in validation3 validator needs to return response');
        }
    });
}

function validation1(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const object = {
            status: random(),
            message: 'message from validation 1'
        };

        callback(object);
    }, 2000);
}

function validation2(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         const object = {
             status: random(),
             message: 'message from validation 2'
         };

         callback(object);
    }, 1000);
}

function validation3(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
         const object = {
             status: random(),
             message: 'message from validation 3'
         };

         callback(object);
    }, 3000);
}

// Helper function for generating random boolean
const random = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;

validator();
```

How can I notify the `validator` function that an error occurred and consequently return?

Thanks for your comments.

Regarding this question has already been answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) I think they do not address the same issue. One deals with synchronicity and asynchrony in javascript instead this question asks about how to handle sequential asynchronous functions and the strategy of how to handle when any of these functions fail.

Thanks to Paul's comment about error-first callback pattern I remember the article about [callbacks](http://javascript.info/callbacks) in [javascript.info](http://javascript.info). After reading I came to this solution.

```js
function validatior() {
    validation1((error, success) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            validation2((error, success) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                } else {
                    validation3((error, success) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error.message);
                        } else {
                            console.log(success);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function validation1(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // callback(new Error('Error message from validation 1'));
        callback(null, true);
    }, 1000);
}

function validation2(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // callback(new Error('Error message from validation 2'));
        callback(null, true);
    }, 2000);
}

function validation3(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(new Error('Error message from vallidation 3'));
        // callback(null, true);
    }, 3000);
}

validatior();
```

This example will stop at `validation3` stopping the `validator` process. I know this is looking like a `callback hell`, but there is in the same post an example about how to alleviate the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: *i cannot use `async/await`* why though?

Comment: just as a side-note, you're kind of breaking an expected pattern in Node.  This kind of thing will often be done with an error-first callback pattern and if validation fails the error object is populated with that, otherwise it's null.  If a passing validation needs to provide no info, then all you need is the null first parameter.

Comment: I am open to suggestions for better ideas to deal with this problem, in fact now I am looking for error-first callback pattern

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning false you could return a promise that resolves on success and gets rejected when the validation fails, e.g.:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

 async function validate() {
   await timer(1000);
   if(/*isValid:*/ false) {
     throw new Error("Validation failed"); // rejection
  } else {
     return true; // resolve
 }
}
```

Then you can easily turn multiple promises into one:

```
 Promise.all([
   validate(),
   validate(),
   validate()
 ]).then(() => {
   // all fine
 }, error => {
   // at least one failed
   console.log(error.message);
 });
```

Comment: thanks for answering, could you please expand the answer in the context in which you validate () is an asynchronous function, I attach a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hqca570f/1/

Comment: @user615274 you have to wrap the callback into a promise, edited